# what should be the java path in the environment variable on my system Windows 10

Tags: java, cmd, environment-variables

[image: Location where my java is installed]

Can someone please let me know what should path for java I need to mention in the environment variable. for java_home etc..Let me know if you need more info from me.
I am very new to the java installation so please excuse if I ask silly question.

Java version : java version "1.8.0_171"

Another strange this is that there is no jdk folder in java. please refer to the link Location where my java is installed...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `JAVA_HOME` it should be `C:\java`, but on your `Path` variable, it should point to `C:\java\bin\` since Path is what is used to tell the Command Prompt where to look for executables.

Comment: You may want to try %JAVA_HOME%\bin to keep it consistent. Whether it works would depend on which one is set first.

Comment: Is the backslash required?

Comment: Forward slash should be fine as well but I haven't tested it. Honestly with the newer versions of Windows, I'd be shocked if it didn't work fine with either slash